# How to make comparision between 2 XML Files- using very fast-runtime?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, shared-libraries, computer-science

I have 2 XML files 
I need very fastest code or library that allow me to compare 2 XML files
and give me the result as the following  :

The code or the library should be compatible with .**NET** {C# or VB.NET}

**XML1:**

```
< tag="environment" value="windows"/>
< tag="gentype" value="Java"/>
```

**XML2:**

```
< tag="gentype" value="C#"/>
< tag="environment" value="windows"/>
< tag="Complexity" value="2"/>
```

Then the result should be something like:

```
< tag="gentype" value="C#" status="**changed**"/>
< tag="environment" value="windows" status="**identical**"/>
< tag="Complexity" value="2" status="**IN_XML2**"/>
```

Comment: Why dont you use the System.Xml namespace and its related functions. This link tells about reading XML using C# - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307548. I dont think adding another library shall be necessary.

Comment: really  I need very fast way/method to get the comparison quickly as possible .
I found something here :
http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/
is this helpful for my status ? or not ?

Comment: Fast is a relative word. How fast it is if you were to use the inbuilt classes.

Comment: Is the tag format as simple as you show it to be? Because if you don't have to do the XML parsing it will be very much faster (basically using line by line file comparison).

Comment: yes this format is quite simple ! and that is all !